# How to listen to external requests with Spark's embedded jetty server

Tags: java, server, ip, jetty, spark-java

I'm setting up a small server for a mobile app, using sparkjava.com. It embeds a jetty server and it works fine when I call like http://localhost:4567/myRequest. But now I want to call it from outside my local environment.

I tried setting the IP adress up with the following :

```
Spark.ipAddress("my-ip")
```

with "my-ip" being what I found on stuff like www.whatismyip.com. But when launching I get

```
[Thread-0] ERROR spark.embeddedserver.jetty.EmbeddedJettyServer - ignite failed
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: bind
```

I have experience with java, but unfortunately not at all with web development itself so I'm a bit lost... Does somone know how it's supposed to work ?

Thank you

Comment: You will have to hire a static IP number from your internet provider and build an infrastructure for this external access. I would recommend you to get started by igniting a free machine at Openshift, Amazon or Azure in order to ger familiar with these external access matters. However it is allready possible to access your application from within your lan with the internal IP for test purposes.

Comment: Also you can try run you server on heroku!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need deploy your web API app to some server. The easiest thing you can do is deploying it to some free PaaS such as heroku. In addition to that, if your API will be called from outside of the server it is running, you will need to implement CORS in Spark.

Here are two tutorials explains how to do it: 
https://sparktutorials.github.io/2015/08/24/spark-heroku.html
https://sparktutorials.github.io/2016/05/01/cors.html

Comment: Sorry for late answer, but thanks, that was what I was looking for :)